# Selecting option in a list not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, html-select

I'm trying to set an option in a list as selected, but the following code is not working in IE8 (works in FF). Does anybody know why (or know a workaround)?

```
$('select option[value="'+image+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: Fyi, while in this case `.val()` is the proper solution as @jperovic answered, you usually do not want to use `.attr()` to set the `selected` or `checked` *attribute* but use `.prop()` instead to set the *property* to a boolean value (this is equivalent to setting `element.checked = true_or_false;`) which is much cleaner than setting a string property which needs to be removed to be unset.

Comment: is their any previous value which is already set as selected?

Comment: @punit - No, no previous value.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Have tried `.prop()` and that is unfortunately not working in either IE or FF.

Comment: *Moderator note:* while it is polite to say "thanks" and "regards", it's not necessary to do so here: politeness and professionalism are implied. Neither is it any more necessary to go on a long-winded discussion on whether or not to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of jQuery do you use in your project?

I think from 1.6 on, you should be able to do

```
$('#my_select').val('some_value');
```

EDIT: As @ThiefMaster pointed out, this is not version dependent:

http://jsfiddle.net/bscJ2/

Comment: You can do that since a very, very long time - not just since 1.6.

Comment: just now I wanted to edit my response as I tried it in JSFiddle :) Thanks!

Comment: I must be doing somehing wrong here, because I cannot get `.val()` to work at all. `$('#qe-taxonomy-term-image').val(image);`, where 'qe-taxonomy-term-image' is the ID of the `<select>` and 'image' holds the correct value that I wish to have selected.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$('option[value=select]').each(function(){this.selected=true;})
```